# rspec cannot determine running spork server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, spork

spork starting output:

```
spork # =>

Using RSpec, Rails
  -- Starting to fill pool...
     Wait until at least one slave is provided before running tests...
  ** CTRL+BREAK to stop Spork and kill all ruby slave processes **
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
Preloading Rails environment
Preloading Rails environment
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Loading Spork.prefork block...
# ... some app output info...
```

Seems like running and it is (i can reach it via browser, there's some response) but every time i try to run specs:

```
rspec --drb -c ./spec/path/to_file # =>

No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
```

Why ?

Thank in advance.

---

environment:

- ubuntu 12.10
- jruby-1.6.8 @ ruby-1.9.2;
- rspec 2.13;

spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'
  require 'capybara/rails' #an alternative to webrat

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/helpers/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :rspec
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
  FactoryGirl.reload
end
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors.  Do you have a `.rspec` that is specifying a different DRb port?  An unlikely but possible issue is that there's some sort of local network problem or port blocking issue.  Can you connect by doing `telnet localhost 8989`?  I doubt that's a problem, but it's worth confirming.

Comment: @JimStewart, yes i could connect with `telnet localhost 8989`. And could you, please, tell where `.rspec` is supposed to be?

Comment: I think it looks in your home dir and the current dir.

Comment: @JimStewart, nope. Seems like there no .rspec in home or app dirs

Comment: Sorry, I'm at a loss then.

Comment: @JimStewart, http://pastebin.com/DbnmpiRz here is `localhost:8989` output if trying to enter something. Nevertheless, thank you.